# HTML with CSS coding

Tags: html, css

Good evening, currently I am working on something where I am having a few issues that I cannot figure out. The current website looks like[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPIZd.jpg). My issues are

1. At the top I would like Super cool tagline will go here to be closer to Art Store
   this text is currently in the body as h2. Art Store is h1
2. Toward the bottom I need the recent acquisitions to be in the top left corner and the three pictures being underneath recent acquisitions. No matter what I try Recent acquisitions never goes to the top left corner of the footer box background.
   recent acquisitions in currently under footer and in 
   images are also in the footer.
3. Border around the pictures.

Can someone please help. I am sure this is an easy fix, but I am new.

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Art Store</title>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="Chapter04-Project03.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Art Store</h1>
            <h2>Super cool tagline will go here</h2>
        </header>
        <article>
            <h2>Still Waiting</h2> 
            <p>Our website will be live in</p> 
            <p id="time">4 years, 3 months, and 2 days</p>
        <h3>*hopefully</h3>
    </article>
            <footer>
        <Text>Recent Acquisitions</text>
                <img src="images/07020.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
                <img src="images/05030.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
                <img src="images/106020.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then here is my css code

```
h1, h2, h3, nav, footer, .actions
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: #150b09 url(images/art-background4.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header
{
    margin-left: 8rem;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33,0.5);
    width: 28rem;
    height: 8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color: white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 -6mm 4mm rgb(33,35,33,0.5));

}
header h2
{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
header h1
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-color: (33,33,33,0.5);
}
article
{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    margin-top: 6rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    margin-left: 8rem;
    width: 30rem;
}
article p
{
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
article h2
{
    background-color:rgba(224,224,224,0.5);
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
article h3
{
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
color: red;
}
article p#time
{
    color: white;
    background-color:rgba(66,66,66,0.5);
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 19rem;
 }
footer text
{
padding-top: 1rem;
}
footer img
{
img-align: top;
}
footer
{
    background-color: rgba(33,33,33,0.5);
    margin-top: 6rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    margin-left: 8rem;
    width: 30rem;
    color: white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 -6mm 4mm rgb(33,33,33,0.5));
    text-align: bottom;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace header tag with below one

```
<header>
<h1>Art Store <span>Super cool tagline will go here</span></h1>
</header>
```

for footer instant of text add p tag

```
<p>Recent Acquisitions</p>
```

And few css changes

```
footer img{
img-align: top;
border-radius: 10px;
}

header h1 span {
font-size: 0.75rem;
}

footer p {
padding:5px;
}
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, nav, footer, .actions
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: #150b09 url(images/art-background4.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header
{
    margin-left: 8rem;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33,0.5);
    width: 28rem;
    height: 8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color: white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 -6mm 4mm rgb(33,35,33,0.5));

}
header h2
{
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
header h1
{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-color: (33,33,33,0.5);
}
article
{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    margin-top: 6rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    margin-left: 8rem;
    width: 30rem;
}
article p
{
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
article h2
{
    background-color:rgba(224,224,224,0.5);
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
article h3
{
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
color: red;
}
article p#time
{
    color: white;
    background-color:rgba(66,66,66,0.5);
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 19rem;
 }
footer text
{
padding-top: 1rem;
}
footer img
{
img-align: top;
border-radius: 10px;
}
footer
{
    background-color: rgba(33,33,33,0.5);
    margin-top: 6rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    margin-left: 8rem;
    width: 30rem;
    color: white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 -6mm 4mm rgb(33,33,33,0.5));
    text-align: bottom;

}
header h1 span {
font-size: 0.75rem;
}

footer p {
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Art Store</title>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="Chapter04-Project03.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Art Store <span>Super cool tagline will go here</span></h1>
            
        </header>
        <article>
            <h2>Still Waiting</h2> 
            <p>Our website will be live in</p> 
            <p id="time">4 years, 3 months, and 2 days</p>
        <h3>*hopefully</h3>
    </article>
            <footer>
        <p>Recent Acquisitions</p>
                <img src="images/07020.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
                <img src="images/05030.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
                <img src="images/106020.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a margin and padding to the headings using css

```
h1,h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

You can add a break row before the images.

```
<Text>Recent Acquisitions</text>
<br>
<img src="images/07020.jpg" alt="This is a test" />
```

You can add the Border using CSS

```
img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
```

You should check out this too, so you can get the countdown timer to automatically work. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! Looking at a bunch of places to learn extra things including udemy.

Comment: Great! Check out w3schools.com too they have lot of tutorials about html, css.